# Curl call from Terminal and Shellscript is diffrent?

Tags: shell, curl, nginx, terminal

I am calling the same curl command once from terminal and once from Shellscript - but the outcome is different:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url="dev.test.ch"
http="http://"
test="192.168.178.107"

curl -H "'Host: $url'" "$http$test"
echo "'Host: $url'" "$http$test"
```

and

```
curl -H 'Host: dev.test.ch' http://192.168.178.107
```

Once I get the NGINX Startpage (from Shellscript) and once the right response (HTML Page from my App)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me -

```
curl -H 'Host: '$newline "$http$test"
```

the braces were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` with `-v` option to see what exactly HTTP request was sent to server. Problem that in your script you `curl` adds `'Host` header.

With this line `curl -H "'Host: $url'" "$http$test"` it sends

```
> GET http://192.168.178.107/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.178.107
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
> 'Host: dev.test.ch'
```

If you remove single qoutes `curl -v -H "Host: $url" "$http$test"` it will send proper request:

```
> GET http://192.168.178.107/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev.test.ch
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
```